# ReactJS ReactCSSTransitionGroup only animating on initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, redux

I am trying to set up animated transitions on route change within my React / Redux app. I have been using examples on SO and the official tutorials as a guide but have so far only been able to get the fade in effect to work on the first load. When changing routes, the components are displayed without any animation in or out.

Am I missing something obvious- and is this the best path to follow when trying to animate the content in / out?

```
/*
**  Loop through ACF components to layout page
*/

blocks = () => {
 if (this.props.pages.pages[0]) {
  return this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components &&
    this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components.map((block, index) => {
      let Component = componentMapping[block.acf_fc_layout];
      return <Component key={index} data={block} id={index} />;
    });
  }
};

/*
**  Render page on state change
*/

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <NavContainer />
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="example"
      transitionAppear={true}
      transitionAppearTimeout={500}
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
    >
      {this.blocks()}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
 );
}
```

The css I have included is as follows :

```
.example-enter {
 opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
 opacity: 1;
}
.example-appear {
 opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
 opacity: 0.01;
 transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

I appreciate any help that anybody could give. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell with just the code you have supplied. I presume you have included all the necessary css to 'fade out' as well as 'fade in'?

Comment: Apologies! Css added above

Comment: It may be because you are using a function call inside the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>`... Try it using just `blocks = this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components.map((block, index) => {...}` instead and see if you have any luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tested without the function call with the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through some troubleshooting steps to get to the bottom of this, but first, let me give you some basic tips on how the ReactCSSTransitionGroup component works.

`<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>` needs to be present on the page with it's children being added and removed after mount. e.g. You have a list of employees that you are filtering based on an input box. As the filter controls what's being added and removed those items are coming and going and being animated. The `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>` must exist first and the component must be mounted.

With React Router, you're mounting and unmounting components as you change routes. If the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>` is inside each component that is being mounted and unmounted the transition will not fire. I think this is what you are experiencing. I would suggest trying out this [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-transitions) to help you take care of animations with route changes.

The issue with your animations only firing once is a separate issue than above. I'm concerned about this part:

```
return this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components &&
    this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components.map((block, index) => {
        let Component = componentMapping[block.acf_fc_layout];
        return <Component key={index} data={block} id={index} />;
    });
```

Returning a variable with the && operator can give you funny results. Try doing some explicit `if` statements. Or honestly just change your code to this:

```
if (this.props.pages.pages[0]) {
    return this.props.pages.pages[0].acf.components.map((block, index) => {
        let Component = componentMapping[block.acf_fc_layout];
        return <Component key={index} data={block} id={index} />;
    });
}
```

Another thought I had was to see what happens when you omit that component creation (`componentMapping[block.afc_fc_layout]`) and just return a `<div>`. See what happens and see if that's what's causing you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response! After more testing I have found that the animation only occurs, when there is a different number of components- so for example, if there are 3 components on the page and then the route changes and there are two, only the last component fades out. The same occurs when there are more components in the next route, so a page with 2 components only animates the last two when going to a page with 4. I have removed the && part of the return and I will look in to the npm package that you recommended. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Be sure and let me know if those suggestions worked! Good luck!